# Android WebChromeClient supply different method on all Android version, how to use them?

Tags: android, webview, webchromeclient

WebChromeClient supply "onShowFileChooser" on Android 5.0, also supply "openFileChooser" method below Android 4.4 method,How to  compatible with them? Has anyone managed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use "Build.VERSION.SDK_INIT" to check the current sdk version on the phone used your app. And decide which to use.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    // do something with onShowFileChooser()
} else {
    //do something with openFileChooser()
}
```

Comment: hi @Luis404,My issue is the method "onShowFileChooser" belong with Android API level 21,but my project is using api level 19,if i use api level 21 or 22，the api won't supply "openFileChooser" method. So, how to do this?